# What to do when all basestars are in the Cylon Fleet board?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, exodus

The last time my group played BSG Board Game, we faced the following situation:

A player took a Crisis Card that activated Basestar Attack. But, at that turn, all the basestars were at the Cylon Fleet board. We haven't reached a consensus, but my thoughts are that all the cylon ships on the space area where the basestars were located (both were at the same space area) should being placed on the same corresponding space area in the main game board. The others players agreed to just move the pursuit marker and do nothing. The same applied when we took an Launch Raiders Crisis Card.

Is that right or am I not understanding the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/exodus/rules/bsg-exodus-rules.pdf) for placing ships on the Cylon fleet board are awkwardly placed over two pages and it appears you missed the second section.  The situation is considerably more dire for the humans that how you played it.  The basestar shows up on the main game board and usually brings a *party* with it.

> If all ships of the appropriate type are already on either the
>   main game board or the Cylon Fleet game board, the current
>   player finds the highest-numbered Cylon space area on the
>   Cylon Fleet game board that contains at least one of that type
>   of ship. He then moves all the ships in that Cylon space area
>   to the corresponding space area on the main game board.

Comment: Correct, although sometimes having small sections jump in is better for humans since it divides the fleet board into manageable chunks and stops the pursuit track ticking up.